# How do I get NetworkManager to assign a fixed MAC address to eth0?

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager, configuration

**Update - Feb 21, 2020:**

I never found an elegant way make NetworkManager assign a particular MAC address to the first/only Ethernet adapter on whatever system my disk happened to boot on.  I also realized I may be able to solve my particular problem by reconfiguring my DHCP server to assign IP addresses based on system names, rather than MAC addresses.  I also started configuring the network on most of my systems via `systemd-networkd`, rather than NetworkManager or netplan.  (`systemd-networkd` may be better, but still has flaws IMO.)  Finally, I am no longer confident that my Oct 14, 2019 update is correct.  In other words, a default install of Ubuntu (maybe 19.10?) may no longer include the `ifupdown` package.

**Update - Oct 14, 2019:**

(Note: As of Feb 2020, I suspect this paragraph may be incorrect and/or out of date.)  This week I installed the desktop version of Ubuntu 19.04.  It appears the package `ifupdown` is installed by default on Ubuntu 19.04.  (Yay!)  Therefore, this question probably only applies to Ubuntu derivatives that have chosen to exclude the `ifupdown` package from their default install.  And the question probably does not apply to Ubuntu itself.  For this and other reasons, I expect I will prefer vanilla Ubuntu over any of its derivatives on all my future installs.

**Original Question - Feb 26, 2019**

In the (distant?) past, I could assign a MAC address to a network interface by adding the following stanza to to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto         eth0
iface        eth0
  hwaddress  00:12:34:56:78:9a
```

As of Lubuntu 18.04, this no longer works (because the `ifupdown` package is not installed by default).

My question is, what configuration file do I edit, and how do I edit it, so that NetworkManager will assign the fixed MAC address of my choice to `eth0`.

(Aside: Yes, I know that by default Ubuntu 18.04 renames `eth0` to a "predictable" name like `enp1s0`.  I have already disabled that renaming, so I do indeed have an `eth0` interface on my system.)

I have glanced at the following documentation:

- [The Gnome NetworkManager.conf documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html)
- [The Gnome nm-settings documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings.html)
- [Thomas Haller's Blog - MAC Address Spoofing in NetworkManager 1.4.0](https://blogs.gnome.org/thaller/2016/08/26/mac-address-spoofing-in-networkmanager-1-4-0/)

Based on the above documentation, I tried adding something like the below to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[device]
match-device=interface-name:eth0
ethernet.assigned-mac-address=00:22:68:1c:59:b1
```

Unfortunately, the above does not seem to work.

My use case is that I have installed Lubuntu onto a USB stick.  Upon boot of the USB stick on any system, I want NetworkManager to assign a predetermined and fixed MAC address to `eth0`.

Comment: as far as i know 18.04 uses `netplan` Probably this link helps you somehow https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1718607 and https://netplan.io/

Comment: The docs says about `assigned-mac-address`: 'Note that this property only exists in D-Bus API. libnm and nmcli continue to call this property "cloned-mac-address".' So maybe you need `cloned-mac-address="00:22:68:1c:59:b1"`?

Comment: @mpb I wonder is NetworkManager is looking for the 'predictable' interface and not eth0.

Answer (score 3):

As said, the property in keyfile format, nmcli, and `NetworkManager.conf` is called `ethernet.cloned-mac-address`. Only on D-Bus API it's called `ethernet.assigned-mac-address` -- that has historic reasons.

Usually you would set this per profile, for example via `nmcli connection modify "$PROFILE" ethernet.cloned-mac-address 00:22:68:1c:59:b1`. By editing `NetworkManager.conf` you specify the default value that is used *if* the per-profile value is unspecified. That's explained in `man NetworkManager.conf`.

After modifying a profile, you need to reactivate it for the changes to take effect. Likewise, if you edit the default value in `NetworkManager.conf`, you need to reload it with `SIGHUP` and reactivate the profile.

Regarding predictable interface names: NetworkManager does not (re)name the device, that's commonly done by udev. You may restrict a profile to an interface by setting `connection.interface-name` to the name that was given to the device. You can see that name with `ip link` or `nmcli device`. Likewise the `match-device=interface-name:` setting for `NetworkManager.conf`.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR:**

```
nmcli con show
```

look for your DEVICE (eth0) in the last column and use the name of the connection for the following command.  Example, if the connection name is "Default":

```
sudo nmcli con modify Default 802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address 00:12:34:56:78:9a
```

**Longer Answer:**

```
nmcli --version
```

NetworkManager is in continuous development and sometimes configuration parameters or their names change.  Some changes are confusing.

Contrast and compare:

- https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/1.10/NetworkManager.conf.html
- https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html

And:

- https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/1.10/settings-802-3-ethernet.html
- https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/settings-802-3-ethernet.html

I faced the same problem with Xubuntu 18.04.  Rant against compatibility-breaking configuration changes omitted.

Answer (score 3):

For wifi connections using network manager (nmcli -v 1.40.0) you can configure a fixed cloned mac address using:

```
nmcli con show
nmcli con modify HotelWifiName wifi.cloned-mac-address 70:48:f7:1a:2b:3c
nmcli device disconnect wlp0s20f3
nmcli device connect wlp0s20f3
```

Very useful when you need to login to hotel wifi captive portals for devices that don't have a browser.

For wired connections, its should be something like:

```
nmcli con show
nmcli con modify Wired ethernet.cloned-mac-address 70:48:f7:1a:2b:3c
nmcli device disconnect enp0s31f6
nmcli device connect enp0s31f6
```